# Prove or disprove that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n i^2 =\mathcal O(2^n )$

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Prove or disprove that $$\sum_{i=1}^n i^2 =\mathcal O(2^n )$$

Can anyone show me how to solve this? I got stuck at the end while comparing exponential with polynomial.

Comment: is it not $2^i$ instead of $i^2$? Explain where you get stuck. Show what you have done.

Comment: The left hand side si $O(n^3)$, so certainly $O^(2^n)$

Comment: Good evening, Sara, and welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange. Unfortunately, I feel I had to flag this. This isn't a site that will solve your homework for you, and some effort or examples of your own thoughts must be shown. That way, we can help you—and others—the best we can. For more information, please read [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Best of luck to you.

Comment: I stuck when I reach n^3/2^n

Comment: n(n+1)(2n+1)/6 = n^3 , F(n) / g(n) = n^3/2^n ?

Comment: Hint: if $i^2 \le A 2^i$ for all positive integers $i$, then $\sum_{i=1}^n i^2 \le A \sum_{i=1}^n 2^i \le 2 A 2^n$.

Comment: I think I got it . Thank you sir Robert for the hint